# How to disable a form in Mozilla Firefox?

Tags: javascript, struts

I am trying to disable the entire form in Mozilla browser. I am using below line to disable the form. In IE it's working fine but in Mozilla it's not working. Could any one help how to disable the entire form which will work in all browser?

```
document.getElementbyId("name").form.disabled="true";
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard way to disable an entire form. You must disable each form control you care about individually.

Using [`myForm.elements`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/form.elements) should help you with this.

Note that the disabled property takes a boolean value (`true` or `false`), not a string. `"true"` only works because browsers will cast a string to a boolean, but this is inefficient and suggests that you can pass the string `"false"` as well (which you can't as that will also be cast to `true`).

Answer (score -1):

try:

```
document.getElementbyId("name").form.setAttribute("disabled","disabled");
```